# Download file from google drive on server

Tags: c#, download, google-drive-api

I use an javascript picker to get file from my google drive, it's work well and i get then download url and acces_token from my drive
I would like to download bytes array from this file from my server, then i path the url and acces_token to it (with ajax), no problem

on server i would get data with this code (it's worked !!!)

```
public void DownloadFile(string url, string AccessToken)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] BB;
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
                BB = wc.DownloadData(url);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

now i get an 403 error ??

url are like "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files.....?key=mykey....."

what's changed on google server ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to download a file using the Drive API and setting the access token in the header, you have to do it by calling this url:

*https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[file-Id]?alt=media*

As it's told in the [Response](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get#response) section in the [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get) endpoint. It's really important the url parameter `alt=media` in order to make it work. Don't use an API Key.

Comment: thanks,yes url have this format https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[file-Id]?key=MyAPIKeyalt=media$source=downloadUrl it's the value of the "downloadUrl" field of the selected file object and "wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);" normally do the job but non autorised error comming .....

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. it's not only about ```googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/…```. You have to use ***alt=media*** instead of ***key=mykey*** if you are using an access token

Comment: ok but alt=media it's allready in url, the url it's sended by google code (in file object, "downloadUrl field"), it's same i'm looking for my google api account.... thanks

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60595512/i-cannot-get-the-file-with-short-lived-url-downloadurl-from-google-drive-api/60651664#60651664) can help you

Comment: Yep, i'm sorry i used the downloadUrl field (https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/FileID?alt=media) and not (like you said) https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/FileID?alt=media !!! That work fine now thank a lot